# How to change locale from get parameter to path in url by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, query-string, redirect

I want to replace url's in .htaccess (301 redirect)
From `www.domain.com/page.html?locale=xx`
To `www.domain.com/xx/page.html`
I can't find right documentation to fix it.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708

Comment: @anubhava, thanks, in that article the same case but other way round -> from page to get. i try, but It does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file to strip off query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^locale=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ $0? [L,NC,R=302]
```